# Flutter test using provider and mock class

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, flutter-provider

I'm testing my Flutter application using Mockito. I have a splash screen that has a provider for state management.

I have a `TokenProvider` class that I want to mock. Consider:

- This class is working fine
- The `SplashScreen` is listening to `TokenProvider` and its consumer is a type of `TokenProvider`.

```dart
class TokenProvider extends ITokenProvider {
  ApiProvider apiProvider = ApiProvider();

  late ResponseModel state = ResponseModel.idle("");
  late Response response;

  getTokenFromServer(String token) async {
    state = ResponseModel.loading("is loading...");
    try {
     // send request for example

    } catch (e) {

    }
      notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then I implemented an `ITokenProvider` which both my mock class and the real `tokenProvider` extend.

```dart
abstract class ITokenProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<void> getTokenFromServer(String token);
}
```

And also, here is my Mock class implementation:

```dart
class MockTokenProvider extends Mock implements ITokenProvider {

  ResponseModel state = ResponseModel.idle("");
  
  @override
  Future<void> getTokenFromServer(String token) async {
    state = ResponseModel.loading("is loading...");
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I show a `CircularProgressIndicator` while loading.

This is my test that I implemented:

```dart
testWidgets('SplashScreen loading state', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  MockTokenProvider mockTokenProvider = MockTokenProvider();
  mockTokenProvider.getTokenFromServer('');

  await tester.pumpWidget(
    Provider<MockTokenProvider>(
      create: (BuildContext context) {
        return mockTokenProvider;
      },
      child: SplashScreen(),
    ),
  );

  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
});
```

I got this error:

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════
> The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building
> _InheritedProviderScope<MockTokenProvider?>(value: <not yet loaded>):
> Error: Could not find the correct Provider<TokenProvider> above this SplashScreen Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
> of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
>   To fix, perform a hot-restart.
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
> Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
> other routes will not be able to access that provider.
>
> - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
>
> Make sure that SplashScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider<TokenProvider>.
> This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
>
> For example, instead of:
>
> ```
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {return Provider<Example>(create: (_) => Example(),
> // Will throw a >ProviderNotFoundError, because context is associated
> // to the widget that is the parent of >Provider<Example>child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),);}
> ```

What is wrong with my test, and how can I improve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of context search type mismatch.

You provide `<MockTokenProvider>`.

The context search is expecting to find provider for `<TokenProvider>`.

`MockTokenProvider` extends `ITokenProvider` but **does not** extend `TokenProvider`.

```
class MockTokenProvider extends Mock implements TokenProvider{
...
```

and also

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
    Provider<TokenProvider>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => MockTokenProvider()
...
```

Should do the trick

Comment: When I extend TokenProvider, the state doesn't update are you sure? is there any document that I can read?

Comment: You should extend `Mock`

Comment: `pub.dev` provides you with usage documentaiton of [https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail] the same for  [https://pub.dev/packages/provider]